# ORA-06553: PLS-801:Internal Error [55018]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, plsql

I want to make a function call like `SELECT URUN_GETIR('test1') FROM DUAL;` but i got **ORA-06553: PLS-801: Internal Error [55018]**.

I tried [ORA-06553: PLS-801: internal error [55018] when testing function returning ROWTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907956/ora-06553-pls-801-internal-error-55018-when-testing-function-returning-rowty) this like for ex URUN_GETIR('test1').KULUSERNAME but getting same error. It didn't work for me.Thanks in advance.

My db table :

[image]

My plsql function code :

```
create or replace FUNCTION URUN_GETIR(KULADI VARCHAR2)
RETURN URUN%ROWTYPE
AS
URUN_TABLO URUN%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO URUN_TABLO FROM URUN ur WHERE ur.kulusername = KULADI;
RETURN URUN_TABLO;
END;
```

[image]

Comment: internal error requires contacting oracle support.

Comment: You must paste code in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with using  [table functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm). Other than that you can not call directly your function like you wanted. Here is another choice for you [Use Stackoverflow Wisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484546/how-to-do-a-function-to-return-row-type-from-a-table-in-pl-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE URUN
(
   CREATED_BY     VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   CREATED_DATE   DATE,
   UPDATED_BY     VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   KULUSERNAME    VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   ID             NUMBER (10)
);

INSERT INTO URUN (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY, KULUSERNAME, ID) VALUES('TEST1',TO_DATE('19000101','YYYYMMDD') ,'TTEST1','USER1',1);COMMIT;
INSERT INTO URUN (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY, KULUSERNAME, ID) VALUES('TEST2',TO_DATE('19000102','YYYYMMDD') ,'TTEST2','USER2',2);COMMIT;
INSERT INTO URUN (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY, KULUSERNAME, ID) VALUES('TEST3',TO_DATE('19000103','YYYYMMDD') ,'TTEST3','USER3',3);COMMIT;
INSERT INTO URUN (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, UPDATED_BY, KULUSERNAME, ID) VALUES('TEST4',TO_DATE('19000104','YYYYMMDD') ,'TTEST4','USER4',4);COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE URUN_OBJ AS OBJECT
(
   CREATED_BY VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   CREATED_DATE DATE,
   UPDATED_BY VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   KULUSERNAME VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR),
   ID NUMBER (10)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE URUN_OBJ_TAB AS TABLE OF URUN_OBJ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION URUN_GETIR (KULADI IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN URUN_OBJ_TAB
   PIPELINED
AS
   REC_OBJ   URUN_OBJ;

   CURSOR DATA
   IS
      SELECT *
        FROM URUN UR
       WHERE UR.KULUSERNAME = KULADI;
BEGIN
   FOR REC IN DATA
   LOOP
      REC_OBJ :=
         URUN_OBJ (REC.CREATED_BY,
                   REC.CREATED_DATE,
                   REC.UPDATED_BY,
                   REC.KULUSERNAME,
                   REC.ID);
      PIPE ROW (REC_OBJ);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END;
/


SELECT * FROM   TABLE(URUN_GETIR('USER1'));

CREATED_BY  CREATED_DATE    UPDATED_BY  KULUSERNAME ID
TEST1   1.01.1900   TTEST1  USER1   1
```